# Where to place a getAll() method when having a Factory

Tags: java, factory

I'm doing a java application.

This are my files so far:

### Person Interface.

has a setName(String aName) method

### PersonImpl

Implementation of Person Interface.

### PersonFactory Interface

has a createPerson()

### PersonFactoryImpl

Implementation of PersonFactory Interface.

The thing is I was willing to add a method getAll() that returns a Collection of Persons and I am not sure where to place it.

I was thinking of adding it as an static method to PersonImpl or to PersonFactoryImpl, but I am not sure.

Which is the best way?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If another implementation of PersonFactory is provided, should it also need to provide a #getAll? If so, it belongs on the interface... and then it can't be a static method in Java.

Given that, is it a function of your PersonFactory or should there be an abstraction for your storage mechanism as well? If so, a PersonRepository interface whose implementations accept a PersonFactory, and provides a natural home for getAll-type functionality seems more appropriate. If not, then as a member of the concrete PersonFactory could be appropriate enough...

Comment: Yes, if there is another impl of PersonFactory it should provide #getAll. To add it to the interface I can make it not static, but doesn't look good.

Please, could you explain better what you mean with PersonRepository?

Comment: Static mutable state is evil - it doesn't make sense, and for bonus points it's difficult to test, is non-obviously multi-threaded and is not secure. For repository - google for the pattern, or Martin Fowler's Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture has it, IIRC.

Comment: BTW: +1 for repository. Probably doesn't need to be an interface though.

Comment: For better, not-database-coupled, unit testing, my implementation pattern is that the Repository must be an interface. YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

The logical way would be to add it as a static method to the `PersonFactory`. That is the class which generates your `Person` objects, and if it keeps references to all generated objects, it should be able to answer your `getAll()` API.

Obviously, it is not reasonable for each `Person` object to be aware of other similar objects, thus this method does not belong there.

**EDIT:** Given the fact that they reside on a database, it might be wise to decouple the `PersonFactory` (which job is to create `Person` objects), from a `PersonRepository` which will be actually accessing the database (or whatever persistency you have) and returning `Person` objects.

It would seem awkward to me that the same class is responsible both for creating objects as well as fetching them from a database. That being said, if your application demands this tight-coupling, it might be acceptable.

Comment: Actually they are saved on a db. the getAll() will get them from there. Don't know if this changes your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The factory is responsible managing instances of Persons, so that is the correct place to put it. Furthermore, it should be non-static just as `createPerson()` is.